# How to print list that I got from findall JpaRepository?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, crud

**LOG I am getting**

```
Hibernate: select * from  resource_hierarchy 
com.att.dmp.entity.ResourceHierarchy@7380c27
```

Instead of ***com.att.dmp.entity.ResourceHierarchy@7380c27***, I want the actual list something like ***ResourceHieracy [ ID = 1, name = Apple, product = Banana]***

```
List<com.att.dmp.entity.ResourceHierarchy>  list  = hesourceHierarchyRepository.findAOI();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        }
```

```
@Repository
public interface ResourceHierarchyRepository extends  JpaRepository<ResourceHierarchy, String> {
    
    
    @Query(value="select * from  resource_hierarchy ", nativeQuery=true)
    List<ResourceHierarchy> findAOI();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you print something it actually calls the `toString()` method of the class. If you want to print something else, lets say the variables of class, override the `toString()` method of `ResourceHierarchy` class and `return` the value of variables from the method as `String`. And it will print your expected values. Something like:

```
public class ResourceHierarchy {
  
  private String id;
  
  private String name;
  
  private String product;
  
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "ResourceHierarchy["  + 
          "id = " + id +
          "name + " + name +
          "product + " + product +
          "]";
  }
}
```

Or alternatively you can use [lambok](https://projectlombok.org/features/ToString) to auto-generate `toString()` code for you.

Comment: How to make use here? `List<com.att.dmp.entity.ResourceHierarchy>  list  = hesourceHierarchyRepository.findAOI();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            System.out.println(list.get(i));
        } `

Comment: You don't have to change here. Just Override toString in ResourceHierarchy  and it will automatically print your expected value here.